# Can I use present perfect with 'once a week'?

Tags: present-perfect

George Hummel usually _____ with members of his department once a week to discuss schedule changes.

a) meeting
b) meet
c) meets
d) have met

The answer is c, Ok,that's easy. But if I change 'have met' into 'has met', is this sentence correct, especially in grammar? So my question is;

George Hummel usually **has met** with members of his department **once a week** to discuss schedule changes.

Is this sentence correct? As a non-native, I'm often confused in using present perfect. So, Can I use present perfect with 'once a week'?

Comment: *has usually met* is much more natural than *usually has met*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present perfect is permissible there, to describe a practice which has been in effect *up to the present moment*.

> **Reporter**: Will Mr. Hummel continue to meet weekly with members of his
>   department?
>   **Press Liaison**: Mr. Hummel *has been meeting* with them once
>   a week, but going forward he may meet with them only once a
>   month. How often they should meet in the future is the subject of today's meeting.

There, the present perfect continuous reinforces the idea of a situation which has been ongoing; the tense corroborates  "once a week".  But we could also say:

> Mr. Hummel *has met* with them once a week...

to express much the same idea, the difference being that in the present perfect **has met** there is no sense of *recurrence*. The phrase **once a week** alone expresses that idea.